# Thumb Drag in MVVM, WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, slider, draggable

I have one working app writen in C# WPF. I like to practice working with MVVM so I like to write same app as MVVM. But I came to a problem. There in my app I use

```
<Thumb DragDelta="Thumb_Drag" 
       DragStarted="Thumb_DragStarted"
       DragCompleted="Thumb_DragCompleted"
       ...
```

How I write this "Drag&Drop/Draggable" example in MVVM? I use "binding" or something else? Any example will be very welcome :) Thanks!

If dont understand please ask me.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to use `System.Windows.Interactivity`library which can be added as a reference in your project.

Add the namespace:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

And call commands through `<i:InvokeCommandAction>`:

```
<Thumb>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="DragDelta">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.ThumbDragDeltaCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Thumb>
```

ViewModel:

```
private ICommand ThumbDragDeltaCommand { get; set;}

public MainViewModel() //Constructor
{
    ThumbDragDeltaCommand = new DelegateCommand(x => 
    {
        //EventHandler
        //Do stuff...
    }
}
```

You can, however, still handle the event in your code-behind while still being committed to the MVVM-pattern as long as the events only trigger graphical changes.

Comment: How does this differ from the answer I posted?

Comment: Any example anywhere on internet? Just to get a filling with it :) It is always easier with some examples :)

Comment: @esispaned I'd say google "WPF Commands MVVM" and "WPF DelegateCommand". There's a lot of resources online and google is your friend :) Also, if this was the answer you were looking for consider marking it as the accepted answer. A sidenote, the DelegateCommand-class isn't part of the BCL yet but you can find an implementation here: [link](http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what kind of logic you have in those event-handlers I wouldn't see a problem in having them in the code-behind. After all MVVM is just a general guideline rather than a strict rule.
If you do insist on implementing them in a view-model you could add a reference to the `System.Windows.Interactivity` dll and use an `InvokeCommandAction` with an `Interaction.Trigger`.

```
<Thumb>
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Thumb_Drag" >
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SomeViewModelCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Thumb>
```